# ora-00351: network library: name-value premature end of string

Tags: c#, visual-studio, oracle12c

I would like to make an application that appends data to the oracle database table, but it does not work properly even if I do not establish the connection and I am getting this error

```
 String ConString = "DATA SOURCE=TEST;DBA PRIVILEGE=SYSDBA;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=DERS;PASSWORD=1234";
        using (Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection con = new Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection(ConString))
        {
            OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO URUNLER VALUES('" + textBox1.Text.ToString() + "','" + textBox2.Text.Count() + "', '" + textBox3.Text + "','" + textBox4.Text + "')", con);
            OracleDataAdapter oda = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet URUNLER = new DataSet();
            oda.Fill(URUNLER);
```

my `app.config` settings;

```
<dataSource alias="TEST" descriptor="TEST=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(Host=192.168.1.27)(Port=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=test))) " />
```

and;

```
<settings>
<settings name="TNS_ADMIN" value="C:\Program Files (x86)\Oracle Developer Tools for VS2013\network\admin" />
</settings>


<connectionStrings>
<add name="TEST" connectionString="User Id=DERS;Password=1234;Data Source=TEST" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
<add name="WindowsFormsApplication5.Properties.Settings.ConnectionString" connectionString="DATA SOURCE=TEST;DBA PRIVILEGE=SYSDBA;PASSWORD=1234;PERSIST SECURITY INFO=True;USER ID=DERS" providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
<clear />
```

finally my `tnsnames.ora` file;

```
TEST =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.1.27)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = test)
    )
  )
```

Comment: What's the base error...all u r saying is that a constructor failed

Comment: base error is ORA-00351

Comment: check this out - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31946158/oracle-manageddataaccess-not-resolving-alias-in-connection-string

Comment: I checked it but it did not work