The underlying provider failed to open connecting to oracle db
Our db team recently made changes to Oracle databases using Oracle 19c, that will function with sqlnet.ora settings on the Linux rhel8 servers of "SQLNET.CRYPTO_CHECKSUM_SERVER=REQUESTED"
Now we upgraded
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess to 21.13.0 and Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.EntityFramework to 21.9.0
still getting the below error. Any suggestions on how this can be resolved.
System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityException: The underlying provider failed on Open. ---> Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException: ORA-00351: Network Library: Name-Value premature end of string ---> OracleInternal.Network.NetworkException: ORA-00351: Network Library: Name-Value premature end of string
   at OracleInternal.Network.NVTokens.PopLiteral()
   at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.GetContext(NVTokens nvt)
   at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadRightHandSide(NVPair nvp, NVTokens nvt)
   at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVPair(NVTokens nvt)
   at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVList(NVTokens nvt, NVPair parent)
   at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadNVList(NVTokens nvt, NVPair parent)
   at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadRightHandSide(NVPair nvp, NVTokens nvt)
   at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.ReadTopLevelNVPair(NVTokens nvt)
   at OracleInternal.Network.NVFactory.CreateNVPair(String nvString)
   at OracleInternal.Network.AddressResolution.<GetEnumerator>d__159.MoveNext()
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.DoConnect(String tnsDescriptor)
   at OracleInternal.Network.OracleCommunication.Connect(String tnsDescriptor, Boolean doNAHandshake, String IName, ConnectionOption CO)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.Connect(ConnectionString cs, Boolean bOpenEndUserSession, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String instanceName)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.PoolManager`3.Get(ConnectionString csWithDiffOrNewPwd, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OraclePoolManager.Get(ConnectionString csWithNewPassword, Boolean bGetForApp, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria, String affinityInstanceName, Boolean bForceMatch)
   at OracleInternal.ConnectionPool.OracleConnectionDispenser`3.Get(ConnectionString cs, PM conPM, ConnectionString pmCS, SecureString securedPassword, SecureString securedProxyPassword, OracleConnection connRefForCriteria)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute(Action operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityClient.EntityConnection.Open()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectContext.ExecuteInTransaction[T](Func`1 func, IDbExecutionStrategy executionStrategy, Boolean startLocalTransaction, Boolean releaseConnectionOnSuccess)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<>c__DisplayClassb.<GetResults>b__9()
   at System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DefaultExecutionStrategy.Execute[TResult](Func`1 operation)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Entity.Core.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.<System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator>b__0()
   at System.Lazy`1.CreateValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.LazyInitValue()
   at System.Lazy`1.get_Value()
   at System.Data.Entity.Internal.LazyEnumerator`1.MoveNext()
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1..ctor(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToList[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
   at HCSS.Contributions.DAL.EmployerDataRepository.GetPartners() in 
the class im trying to access


Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/51390188/1509264 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/31946158/1509264
